# (n_jobs = -1) TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated

Tags: python, data-science, jupyter, joblib

I have an error when I run this :

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipeline,
    param_grid=param_grid,
    cv=tscv,
    scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
    verbose=1,
    n_jobs=-1
)
```

The error is raised because of `(n_jobs=-1)`

My new laptop specifications;
Dell G15, Core I7, RAM:16GB
Environment : Python 3.7.1

The old laptop worked properly.

I searched a lot to solve this error but I didn't find any solution.
What could I do to solve this and make all available cores run in parallel.